# Linking stylesheets from main site to Wordpress child theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website not running on Wordpress, but have installed Wordpress in the /blog sub directory. I'm trying to modify the chosen Wordpress theme to match the header of my website. I've managed to come relatively close, but by placing duplicate .css and .js files within the child theme.

What I want to do is give the proper path while enqueueing from functions.php - I'm just unfamiliar with .php and how to do so. Here's what I have:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'freelance-main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '../../../freelancer.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '../../../bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '../../../bootstrap.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    array('parent-style')
);
}
?>
```

From viewing the page source it's actually trying to load the "../" in the url so I know this isn't right, I just don't know how to type it properly. Here's the structure:

root 
-mywebsite
--blog
---wp-content
----themes
-----child-theme
--css
---needed files
--js
---needed files

Like I said, if I duplicate the files and put them in the child-theme it works, but I don't think this is best practice.